# Can I change my vote during the exploration period?

Tags: voting

Is it possible for someone to change their vote during the exploration period?

Let’s assume I voted “pass” at the beginning of the period to signal my participation and help achieve the quorum. Can I change my vote subsequently to “yay” or “nay” once I feel I have all the information necessary to take my final decision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Attempting to do so will result in an "unauthorized_ballot" error in [amendment.ml](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/mainnet/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/amendment.ml#L242).

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. But there is another vote during the last round, after the test period. The vote during the exploration period ensures that no malicious code ends up being promoted to the testnet. But the real decision comes after some testing and enough time to understand the real effects of the change.